# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dftd3'

Tags: python3

I am getting a File not found error even though the file is available in the directory. Can someone help me please?

I am using the ASE package to perform DFT calculations. I am using GPAW package which is a calculator for the DFT. Additionally i wanted to also include dispersion correction (which is performed by DFTD3).
i used the second example from this documentation 'https://wiki.fysik.dtu.dk/ase/ase/calculators/dftd3.html' as a reference to set up the calculators where i stumbled upon the error.

Some more details related to the error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/lbfgs.py", line 65, in __init__
Optimizer.__init__(self, atoms, restart, logfile, trajectory,master,
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/optimize.py", line 234, in __init__
self.set_force_consistent()
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/optimize/optimize.py", line 325, in set_force_consistent
self.atoms.get_potential_energy(force_consistent=True)
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/atoms.py", line 728, in get_potential_energy
energy = self._calc.get_potential_energy(
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 709, in get_potential_energy
energy = self.get_property('energy', atoms)
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/dftd3.py", line 387, in get_property
dftd3_result = FileIOCalculator.get_property(self, name, atoms,
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/calculator.py", line 737, in get_property
self.calculate(atoms, [name], system_changes)
File "/home/sachin/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ase/calculators/dftd3.py", line 220, in calculate
errorcode = subprocess.call(command,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 345, in call
with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1863, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dftd3'
```

Error Information:

[image: Error Information]

File in the directory:

[image: File in the directory]

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for your input. I have made some changes to my question. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the error. I initially thought that the DFTD3 calculator is implicitly available within he ASE framework but i was wrong.

I had to externally install the DFTD3 package and integrate it to the ASE.
Here is the link [for further details](https://pypi.org/project/dftd3/).